# Does Systemverilog color work for vi?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I've added the correct $display in Systemverilog to use colors in my log file. Looks great when I use 'more' but vi doesn't show the color. Is there a .vimrc setup file I need to define. I don't have one. I've seen some recommendations on adding 'aubBufNewFike..' but that didn't work.

It works for more so I think it's more of a Linux setup environment issue

Here's the code to set color

$display("%c[1;34m",27);

Answer (score 1):

Well… `'aubBufNewFike..'` will certainly not work as it doesn't mean *anything*.

Apparently, `$display("%c[1;34m",27);` inserts escape sequences in the output of your program. Your problem, here, is that Vim, being a plain text editor, is incapable of interpreting those escape sequences.

From there, you can…

- simply keep reading your log files in `more` or `less`, which is the only thing that makes sense given the nature of the task and that of the material,
- or [look for a suitable plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?order_by=creation_date&direction=descending).